# React component not re-rendering with connect()

Tags: reactjs, redux

My reducer:

```
export default function summary(state = {
  "summary":null
}, action = null) {
    switch (action.type) {

    case GET_SUMMARY_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
        const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        newState.summary = action.data;
        return newState;
        break;
    case GET_SUMMARY_REQUEST_ERROR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          sumary:null
        });
        break;

    default: return state;
    }
};
```

Root reducer:

```
import summary from './Summary.js'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    summary
});
```

Inside my component, I am using connect to map state to props>
My components render function is something like this:

```
render() {
    const summary = this.props.summaryContent || [];
        return (
            <div className={cx(styles['loading'])} >
              <Loader width="4" />
              {"Loading\u2026"}
            </div>
        );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownParams) {
    return {
        summaryContent: state.summary
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Summary);
```

On componentWillMount, I am dispatching an action to update in the state in summary. Now, my componentWillReceiveProps is showing me the updated state in summary, but the component is not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues here:

1. You use `summary` both as a reducer key and as an index in your reducer state. That means `summaryContent` should map to `state.summary.summary`. (Though I'd suggest changing it to adopt a less confusing naming convention.)
2. Your render function doesn't utilise `this.props.summaryContent` in any useful way. It simply assigns it to a variable and then returns a loading output.
3. You've misspelled `summary` in the `GET_SUMMARY_REQUEST_ERROR` case.

I strongly recommend configuring ESLint which will alert you to issues like unused and misspelt variables.